# Inner production over the complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Can you help me find an example for $\,u,v \in \Bbb C^2\,$ unit vectors that $\langle u,v\rangle\neq 0$ and $\|u+v\|=\sqrt 2$
2. $u,v$ over $C^n$ and we know that $\|u\|=\|u+v\|=\|u-v\|$
   need to prove $v=0$

after I opened every thing I got to this:
$4Re(\langle u,v\rangle)=\langle u,u\rangle$ but I don't see how it helps me.

Comment: Check my edit reflects correctly your intention

Comment: For the first, consider $1,i \in \mathbb{C}$. Then both have unit length, their product is non-zero and $|1+i|^2 = 2$. Extend this trivially to $\mathbb{C}^n$. For the second, I hope you got $\text{Re} \langle u , v \rangle = 0$ instead. The answer to 2) follows directly from this.

Comment: I changed $<u,v>$ to $\langle u,v\rangle$ and $||x||$ to $\|x\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to problem 2.
Lets break this down:

1. $||u||=||u+v||$
2. $||u+v||=||u-v||$

From 1 you will get: $\langle u,u\rangle=\langle u+v,u+v\rangle$
From 2: $\langle u+v,u+v\rangle=\langle u-v,u-v\rangle$ and from there you easily get to: $\langle u,v \rangle = - \overline{\langle u,v \rangle}$. Place that into the first equation and you will get your answer.

Regarding your first question:
You can simply define $a=(a_1,a_2)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)$ place into the [standard complex inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_form#Hermitian_form) and solve.